# How to conditionally change Parent Status in Jira

Tags: groovy, jira, status, jira-plugin, jql

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**
In Jira, on a transition, in a workflow for parent issues, I want to create a post function that will **Automatically** Update the parent status ("Fast-track transition" with the Script Runner plugin) **IF** a specific sub-task has been transitioned to "Completed"

**How do I write that Condition using Script Runner?**

I will have many of these similar post-functions attached to several transitions in the work flow, and each Post-function will be looking for a unique Issue-type (Sub-task) to be closed before it updates the parent status. Also will using this "Fast Track" script automatically listen for the sub-task to actually be "completed" or will this transition (located in the parents workflow) have to be triggered by something else? Here's what I have so far:

```
status = 'Completed' AND type = 'Outline 1.0' AND issueFunction in subtasksOf(" [[Current parent issue]] ")
```

Documentation on this can be found [HERE](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Built-In+Scripts#Built-InScripts-Fast-tracktransitionanissue), but I just don't know how to write the condition properly. Below is what the Script Runner Screen looks like when I try to set this up. Thanks in Advance!
[image]